# How to fix passport local authentication error that prevents registered users from logging in

Tags: express, mongoose, passport.js, ejs, passport-local

I have spent some time tring to figure out why the code for my passport local authentication is not functioning properly but I haven't
been able. The program has username field and password field. So people can register with their username and password. The issue in the code lies
in the login section. If I login with any registered username and password, the browser displays **Data not found** instead of displaying
the content of the redirected page. Please, what could be responsible for this error. The code for the program is shown below.

Auth schema file:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");
    
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
    type: String,
    required: true
    },
    password: String,
});

userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
    
const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
module.exports = User;
```

Setup

```
const express = require("express");
const Post = require("./../models/post");
const User = require("./../models/user")

//Connecting mongoose with mongodb

const  mongoDB = "mongodb://localhost/blog";
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/blog", {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex: true
});
const db = mongoose.connection;

//Adding success or error message to node console
db.on("error", console.error.bind(console, "connection error:"));
db.once("open", function(){
    console.log("Connection successful");
});

const router = express.Router();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
router.use(bodyParser.json());

//const User = require("../models/user");
var passport = require("passport");
var localStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;

//Passport configuration
router.use(require("express-session")({
   secret: "A programmer",
   resave: false,
   saveUninitialized: false
}));

router.use(passport.initialize());
router.use(passport.session());
passport.use(new localStrategy(User.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());
```

Auth routes:

```
router.get("/new", isLoggedIn, (req, res) => {
   console.log(req.params)
   res.render("new", {post: new Post()});
})

router.get("/register", async(req, res)=>{
   res.render("register");
})

router.post("/register", function(req, res){
   req.body.username
   req.body.password
   var newUser = new User ({username: req.body.username})
   User.register(newUser, req.body.password, function (err, user){
      if(err){
         console.log(err)
         return res.render("register")
      }
      passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function(){
         res.redirect("login");
      })
   })
})

router.get("/login", function(req, res){
   res.render("login");
});

router.post("/login", passport.authenticate("local", {
   successRedirect: "new",
   failureRedirect: "login",
}), (req, res, next)=>{

})
router.get("/logout", (req, res)=>{
   req.logout();
   res.redirect("login")
})
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next){
   if(req.isAuthenticated()){
      return next
   }
   res.redirect("login")
}
```

Login template file `(login.ejs)`

```
<%- include ('partials/header') %>
    <div class="container mb-4 mt-4">
        <div>
        <span class="loginIcon float-right"><img src="/public/images/e73b6446-110b-413d-9c0a-1d05fa9acc6e.jfif" alt="login icon"></span>
        <h2 class="text-center">Login</h2>
        </div>
    <form action="posts/login" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="author">Username</label>
        <input required type="text" name="username"  class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Please enter your Username">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input required type="password" name="password" class="form-control" id="title" placeholder="Please enter your password">
    </div>
    <div class="text-center">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg btn-block mb-2">Submit</button>
    <a href="/" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-lg btn-block">Cancel</a>
    </div>
</form>
    <div class="text-center"><a href="/posts/register">Sign up if you don't have an account</a></div>
    
</div>
    <%- include ('partials/footer') %>
```

Answer (score 0):

After some time I have been able to find out Why the browser was displaying data not found when a registered user tried to login. The issue was from the middlewere. And since failureRedirect was working appropriately, the issue came from the next method of the middlewere. It should be:

```
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next){
   if(req.isAuthenticated()){
      return next()
   }
   res.redirect("login")
}
```

The issue occurs when the parentesis at the end of the returned next function is omitted. Hence, it should be  `return next()` not `return next`